# Locating an edge index in an edge features matrix

Tags: python, algorithm

I have an undirected graph `G` with `3 nodes`: `a,b,c`. I create `U` the set of all possible edges in the graph: `U = [(a,b), (a,c), (b,c)]`

I have matrix `M` that has shape of `3_by_4`. Each row represents the a feature vector for a possible edge, so `M[0]` is feature vector for edge (a,b). Elements in `M` has the corresponding indices as in `U`.

Now my problem is that given two nodes `(x,y)`, which row in matrix `M` is their feature vector?

This a bit complicated since I have two possibilities: (x,y) and (y,x).

The naive approach I'm considering to solve this is the following:

- Create a dictionary `E = {(x,y) : their_U_index}`. So for each possible edge in `U`, I put `(x,y)` as a key and the index of `(x,y)` in `U` as their index in `M`
- Given two nodes (x,y) do:

`if (x,y) in E:
     index = E[(x,y)]
     #get the feature vector M[index] ... then do something with it
else:
     index = E[(y,x)]
     #get the feature vector M[index] ... then do something with it`

However I have a concern that doing `if (x,y) in E` might be slower that doing:

```
index = E[(x,y)]
```

then if I got an KeyError exception, I try with the other combination.

Now my questions are:

1- Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

2- Is `if (x,y) in E` as fast as catching from an exception?

ps. of course imagin *lots* of nodes not just 3. It was just to make explaining easy.

Comment: If the graph is undirected, then `(a,b) = (b,a)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
index = E[(max(x, y), min(x, y))]
```

Better yet, wrap this in a function and call the function instead.

But if your graph contains an edge between *every* pair of nodes, then there's a simple relationship.  Assuming you have a pair of nodes x and y with x > y (if not, swap them) and you store all edges in the order (1, 0), (2, 1), (2, 0), (3, 2), (3, 1), (3, 0), ..., then for each x value the list of edges for all y values appears as a contiguous block, and the position where this list begins increases quadratically with x:

```
index = x*(x-1)/2 + y
```

Assuming 0-based indices for x, y and the index into the edge array.